# Store topic specific data for a Phoenix Channel

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Given a `Channel` that has multiple users connected to a specific topic, say `"rooms:lobby"`, I'd like to be able to store information associated to the channel that I can retrieve and possibly update every time a new message comes in. In a sense, I want each topic to be its own `GenServer-like` thing.

From what I can tell, `Phoenix.Socket.assign/3` stores information that is local to each user, and thus would not work.

Comment: I can't quite tell @Havvy but I think you're conflating a couple of different concepts.  I think Channel is a Phoenix concept where as "rooms" is something specific to your chat app.  Maybe rephrase your question?  It's sort of confusing as it stands right now.

Comment: Yeah, reading the reference documentation a bit more, I see that it's called a 'topic', and not a room. I'll update the question to use the correct terminology.

Comment: Do you want to store the information in memory only or persist it? What kind of data, like entire conversations or 'meta-ish' data around amount of events/time/etc?

Comment: I think I understand @Havvy's question and it can seem seen this way: if Phoenix let you do `def join("room:" <> roomid, _params, socket) do`, how do I access `roomid` in `handle_in` or `handle_out`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't quite figure out what you're asking but if I were you, I'd look at using [Elixir Agents](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html) to try to do what you're doing.  I'd post the portion of the Agents doc I'm looking at but, as I say, I'm not sure I am understanding your question correctly anyway.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because it's ultimately what I did, but that's not really /using/ Phoenix, rather just adding a cludge for something that doesn't seem to be there.